# Can $Z(R_R)$ contain a direct summand of $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

In theorem 14.7 in the book below, they claim that the singular submodule of $R$ cannot contain a direct summand of $R$, but I cannot understand why.

[Surender Kumar Jain, Ashish K. Srivastava, and Askar A. Tuganbaev. **Cyclic modules and the structure of rings.** Oxford University Press, 2012](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=9v1AAm7xP-oC&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=R/soc(R)+is+noetherian+if+every+injective+hull+of+singular+simple+module&source=bl&ots=fDpXfcriNJ&sig=ACfU3U3qfZ535K23v_VnX_RHGCy6pnqOdA&hl=vi&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSq4OXs7nnAhWTF3IKHaMXDEMQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=R%2Fsoc(R)%20is%20noetherian%20if%20every%20injective%20hull%20of%20singular%20simple%20module&f=false) page 134.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direct summand of $R_R$ takes the form of $eR$ where $e$ is an idempotent element.

If $eR$ were contained in the right singular submodule of $R$ for a nontrivial idempotent $e$, that would imply the right annihilator $\mathscr{r}(e)$ is an essential submodule of $R$.

But it isn't: it is easy to prove that $\mathscr{r}(e)=(1-e)R$, which is a nontrivial summand, and therefore impossible to be essential.